# WSO2 Security - Apply a keystore for service when securing

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

An Axis2 service can be secured using setServicePolicy operation in ServiceAdmin. However, even when the policy have the rampart configuration, when I examine from the admin console it doesn't select the default keystore for that service. Because there's no keystore selected this service cannot be invoked.
Need to manually go to the UI and select the tenant's default keystore.
When we use ServiceAdmin to secure a service programmatically how to specify what keystore to use to secure it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a separate service called applySecurity() in https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/security/org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt/4.2.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/security/keystore/service/SecurityConfigAdmin.java to do this task.